# Can't get Angular Routing to route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm building the template of my angular 7 app, but the routing is not working as expected. I am not getting errors from either compiling or runtime, but when I try and display the simple content of the component I want to route to, nothing is displayed. The address bar shows that it thinks it's in the correct route, but my html for that component is not displayed.

The whole project is available on github at
https://github.com/cpeddie/TRACS3.git

I've followed a bunch of different tutorials, so I don't understand what is going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had the  tags in the wrong place in the app.component.html file. They need to be within the sidenav content tags.

Comment: That's what I was pointing in my answer, I would also recommend that you move the navbar into a separate component for easier customization and code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Checked your code, try this change

**Add tags in the sidenav tags in your app.component.html**

1. No need to import Router Module in App module. Just import your custom AppRouting module

**Paste below in your app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material'; 
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material'; 
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material'; 
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material'; 
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material'; 
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
import { SettingsComponent } from './components/settings/settings.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { BugReportComponent } from './components/bugreport/bugreport.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './components/logout/logout.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    BugReportComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    LayoutModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UI is great, your folder organization is on point, even your routing works just fine, your particular mistake is this:

Inside app.component.html, you set an inline style to the upper-most div.

```
style="height: 100vh;
```

This is causing the navbar containter to occupy the full vertical height of your webpage, thus making it impossible for you to see the content you want to display in your other components. Removing this styling makes it all work!

Furthermore, i would change it to something like:

```
margin-bottom: 50px;
```

to separate the navbar from the content you want to display. Hope this solves your problem!